# PHP PDO updating multiple records instead of one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm making a basic Poll script for college assignment, but I somehow am not able to update a single row of SQL. Instead all of the rows are updates.

So here we got a first part of script which pulls all associated records from selected poll ID. Lets call this script **show.php**

```
 <?php

     $pid = (int)$_GET['pid'];

     $query = " 
            SELECT 
                 Player_ID,
                 Player_Name
            FROM players WHERE Team_ID = :pid
        "; 

    $query_params = array( 
            ':pid' => $pid, 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    ?>

    <div class="container contain well">

    <h3>Please select player</h3>

    <form action="vote.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $_GET['pid']; ?>" />
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
          <input type="radio" name="player" value="<?php echo $row['Player_ID']; ?>" id="<?php echo $row['Player_ID']; ?>"><label for="<?php echo $row['Player_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Player_Name']; ?></label><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <input type="submit" value="Vote &raquo;" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>

    </div>
```

now ones user selects which player he wishes to vote for the script sends a POST request to lets say **vote.php**

```
    <?php
         require("database.obj.php");

            $pid = (int)$_POST['pid'];

            $query = " 
                UPDATE players 
                SET 
                    Player_Votes = Player_Votes+1; 
                WHERE
                    ( Player_ID = :player )
            "; 

            $query_params = array( 
                    ':player' => $_POST['player']
            ); 

            try 
            { 
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex) 
            { 
                die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
            } 

            header("Location: results.php?pid=$pid");
            die("Redirecting to results.php?pid=$pid");
```

and finally here is the **results.php** page which displays the results

```
     $pid = (int)$_GET['pid'];

     $query = " 
            SELECT 
                 Player_ID,
                 Player_Name,
                 Player_Votes
            FROM players WHERE Team_ID = :pid
        "; 

    $query_params = array( 
            ':pid' => $pid, 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    ?>

    <div class="container contain well">

    <h3>Player results</h3>

    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
          <p><?php echo $row['Player_Name']; ?>
          <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $row['Player_Votes']; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $row['Player_Votes']; ?>%;">
              <?php echo $row['Player_Votes']; ?> Votes
              </div>
          </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 

    </div>
```

The problem is with either show.php or vote.php (vote.php processes the UPDATE query) however i'm not sure where the issue is at. As I said the data is inserted into Players_Votes but its inserted for all 5 players associated with lets say Team_ID = 1

Can some one help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Tanatos nope. The $query_params get there $_POST from the radio input <input type="radio" name="player" value="<?php echo $row['Player_ID']; ?>

Comment: The `UPDATE` statement looks correct - did you examine your table to be sure that all the players actually have different `Player_ID` values (assume so, as that is probably a PK).  Are you working and testing in a hosting environment, to which you haven't uploaded the most recent file version (that happens often around here too)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski each player has a unique Player_ID (int 2, primary, AI). Team_ID is static to correspond to the players team Ex: Brazil = 1, Germany = 2. No matter what I try for some reason it updates all votes for every player even so its being given the ID it should update. I honestly hate PDO for being so confusing as compared to old good mysql_* but for this assignment it needs to be in PDO. Its running on localhost as well so its always the latest updated code.

Comment: Temporarily, change the `UPDATE` statement to use a static value in the where clause: `WHERE Player_ID = 2` (then you need to pass an empty array or nothing to `execute()`) -- does only player 2 get updated then?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski nope. It still updates everything. If I run Player_Votes = +1; it updates everything to 1 and stays at 1 no matter how many times I resubmit. If I run Player_Votes = Player_Votes+1; it will update everything as it should numerically (2,3,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon (`;`) in your update statement before the `where` clause. This breaks your statement in to two statements - an `update` without a `where` clause, which updates all the records (as you noted), and a statement starting with `where` that should just fail since it isn't valid SQL.

To fix it, you should remove that semicolon:

```
$query = " 
            UPDATE players 
            SET 
                Player_Votes = Player_Votes+1 -- Semicolon removed here
            WHERE
                ( Player_ID = :player )
        ";
```